# unittest stderr messages python

Tags: python, unit-testing, stderr

I have wondering how to implement a test using unittest in python in order to ensure all the messages of a program showed by stderr are correct and working as expected.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Helpful external post: http://schinckel.net/2013/04/15/capture-and-test-sys.stdout-sys.stderr-in-unittest.testcase/

Comment: Do you want to test some messages produced by a print function to sys.stderr instead of testing a return value of the function?

Comment: Exactly, the sys.stderr is the best way I have to ensure the workflow works as expected